# Can we connect to iPhone from Android device even though not in the same network?

Tags: android, ios, networking, wifi-direct, nsd

I am working around wifi direct and NSD (Network Service Discovery) to transfer files.

1. **[NSD](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html)**: where serivce has been created and can scan the other devices which are publishing the same service with in the same network.
2. **[WiFi Direct](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html)**: This is used to scan the near by devices without network
3. **[WiFi P2P Network Serice Discovery](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html)**: This is used scan the service near by devices where other devices provide the same service (NSD+WiFi Direct)

As per requirement, I need to give compatibilty to iOS device even though both are not in same network. I came to know that NSD is similar to Bonjour service by iOS.But this can be possible when devices are in the same network.

Is there any way to get connect to iPhone when both are not in same not network?

Comment: Well... If we're talking about different networks, why not simply creating your own web service for that?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the intricacies of getting Android and iOS to play nice together, it is possible to make them think they are in the same network without physically being there. If I understand you correctly, seems like you have two options:

1. Setup up a VPN server in network A and the device in network B connect to it. This would make the device in network B think it was on network A, and have access to all LAN services (such as NSD).
2. Set up VLAN trunking on a switch and put network A in the same network as B.

Option 2 would only work if they were geographically in the same area (like on the same campus). Option 1 would be preferable if they were geographically disparate, or you were unable or unwilling to make the infrastructure changes necessary to support option 2.